# Mariadb vs MySQL query execution time

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

MariaDB execution plan
[image: Mariadb Query Profiling]
MySQL execution plan
[image: MySQL Query Profiling]

I have run same query on MySQL and Mariadb with same resources, but in Mariadb it takes much more time than mysql. I think In MySQL sending data is the issue. any ideas?

here are explains:

[Mysql query explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQOIC.png)
[MariaDB query explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI7kv.png)

Comment: "Sending data" is one of 2 or 3 stages where Profile says the query takes most of its time.  Useless info.  `EXPLAIN` might provide info on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

The Optimizers diverged at MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB 10.0; they have continued to diverge since then (now 8.0 and 10.5).  I find some queries run faster in one product or the other.

For a newbie -- pick whichever product is convenient.  For an expert, with a big database -- try both forks; it would be hard to predict which would be better for you.

If you would like to describe your application, we might be able to guide you more specifically; or tell you "either one".